# using nl2br after decrypting a record in a mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

In past, when I want to display a text-content (textarea -> mySQL Database) in HTML, I used nl2br to display the content correctly in HTML.

Now I want to do this after decrypting the database-content, but it doens´t work.

```
$note = openssl_decrypt($note, "AES-256-CBC", "$encode_key", 0 , "$encode_key");
$outputNote = str_replace("\r\n", "test", "$note");
echo $outputNote;
```

What´s is wrong in this solution?

Comment: One thing that is not strictly “wrong”, but nonsense stuff newbies always do: Putting string variables into additional quotes for no reason. // What have you done so far to _verify_ that your `$note` actually contains `\r\n`?

Comment: _"using nl2br after decrypting..."_ - I don't see you using `nl2br()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: $note is taken out of a mySQL Database using "mysqli_fetch_assoc".

echo nl2br($note); .... trying before str_replace (taking no effekt)

Comment: Show us the complete code you're having issues with. The posted code doesn't match your title. Also, do a `print_r($note)` and check if it actually contains any line breaks.

Comment: echo nl2br($note) output:

Das ist ein Testsatz\r\n\r\nNeuer Absatz

Comment: print_r($note) generates the following result:
Das ist die erste Zeile (first row)\r\n\r\nDas ist die zweite Zeile (second row after 2 returns)

Answer (score 0):

ok. Thats the full code generating note

```
$sql_notes = "SELECT content FROM gn_notes WHERE userid = '$sessionID' ORDER BY tstamp DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db_link, $sql_notes);
$number=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($number > 0) {
    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $date = date("d.m.Y", $record['tstamp']);
        $time = date("H:i", $record['tstamp']);
        $note = $record['content'];
        /* LOOKING FOR ENCODE_KEY */
        $encode_key = getValue('encode_key', 'gn_user', $sessionID, $db_link);
        $note = openssl_decrypt($note, "AES-256-CBC", "$encode_key", 0 , "$encode_key");
        echo nl2br($note);
    }
}
```

That is the output in the website:
[Screenshot ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTd6D.png)

Comment: 1. Don't post additional info as an _answer_. Edit your question instead. 2. If it prints out `\r\n`, it seems like you don't have line breaks in the file, but rather the literal strings `\r\n`. How was this stored in the DB to start with?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I´m sorry for posting the infos as an answer. The content is coming from a textarea (user added) and will encrypted. After this, the string will saved in an mySQl Database in a field type "text". Sorry for my bad English. I hope, I wrote right.